# jsonobject for nested api's put operation

Tags: json, string, put, rest-assured

i am trying to put request by using jsonobject but i couldnt find a way to send it
how can i create put body for api like

```
    {
  "roleRight": {
    "systemSetting": 0,
    "userManagement": 0
  }
}
```

right now, i created like;

```
public static JSONObject nspRightSet(String ssvalue, String umvalue) {
        JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
        requestParams.put("roleRight.systemSetting", ssvalue);
        requestParams.put("roleRight.userManagement", umvalue);
        return requestParams;
    }
```

and use it by;

```
res = given()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + localLogin.accessToken)
                .header("Content-type", "application/json")
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(nspRightSetBody)
                .when()
                .put("https://localhost:8090/api/v1/roles/" + rolenameId + "/right")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .statusCode(201)
                .extract()
                .response().getBody();
    }
```

but it gives error like;

```
"error": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `...` out of START_ARRAY token;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static JSONObject nspRightSet(String ssvalue, String umvalue) {

        JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject childJSON = new JSONObject();
        childJSON.put("systemSetting", ssvalue);
        childJSON.put("userManagement", umvalue);
        requestParams.put("roleRight", childJSON);
        return requestParams;
    }
```